# Grease pencil fill materials does not render while stroke does

Tags: rendering, materials, grease-pencil

I have a problem with a file where the Grease Pencil fill materials won't render while the stroke ones will.

I tried the following : appending object in another file, switching sequencer in the Output > Post Processing panel, rendering using the compositing output.

I have another file with the same materials that works, so I think it might be a bug.
Here is a screenshot of my scene :
[image: Here is my blender scene]

And Here is the rendered image. As you can see only the stroke appears.
[image: rendered image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pFA9p8N7fUzSA8IITyI3PdAKEvslXbni/view?usp=sharing) is a link with the blend file, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qh4sMS2E1hNBvcGbZ116zPotSu5Knp3S/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a working file (The files are a bit heavy due to packed textures).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I fixed it by resetting this value to "ViewLayer" for the fill object. Seems like it was attached to an outdated or deleted view layer called "Perso". It seems to render fine with that done.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You  saved my day! :D